# Set HTTP header x-frame-options: deny in nginx.ingress does not work

Tags: http-headers, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I try to set the Http Response Header *x-frame-options: deny* as:

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: Deny";
    more_set_headers "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin";
```

But the response Header gets set to SAMEORIGIN:

[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCuLD.png)

Any ideas whats wrong in my config?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the below annotation that you have added

`more_set_headers "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin";`